# SqlLiteDatabase catching exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I have my table in database

```
CREATE TABLE Opponent (
    Opponent_ID integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Opponent_Add_Date text,
    Opponent_Name text UNIQUE
);
```

Then I'm trying to insert query to database

```
String query = "INSERT INTO Opponent (Add_Date, Opponent_Name) VALUES ('date' , 'name');"
```

The problem occurs, when I want to add existing opponent name, my app crushes. If I'm trying to catch my exception with `SQLiteConstraintException`, however then it allows adding two Opponents with the same name. For catching it I'm using:

```
try {
     SQLiteStatement statement = mDataBase.compileStatement(query);
     statement.execute();
} catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
      Log.e("insert", "SQLException: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
}
```

Could anyone tell me how to catch the moment, when two the same names are added?

Comment: Are you sure you get two entries? The code looks correct.  Also, your SQL seems to be always inserting the same values!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to do nothing if the name already exists, then you can use [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) instead.

However, if you also need to retrieve the ID of the already-existing row, then you should just execute a SELECT first, and do the INSERT only if the row is not found.